# Min and Max using Subquery

Tags: java, criteria

my table1 has 4 columns (Column1,Column2,e,table2ID(this one is a ManyToOne)) the values of e and table2ID are the inputs of my methode i'm trying to retrieve the line that corresponds to: the value of e+table2ID (received) +max(Column1)+min(Column2) from table1 this is the error i've got:

> > org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token: ) near line 1, column 483 [select generatedAlias0 from table1 as generatedAlias0, table1 as generatedAlias1 where ( generatedAlias0.table2ID.table2ID=10200L ) and ( generatedAlias0.e=1L ) and ( generatedAlias0.isEnd=false ) and (
> >     generatedAlias0.Column1 in (select max(generatedAlias2.Column1) from table1 as generatedAlias2) ) and ( generatedAlias0.Column2in (select min(generatedAlias1.Column2) from ) )]

and this is my code :

```
public table1 find(final Long table2ID, final Long e) {

    final CriteriaBuilder builder = getCriteriaBuilder();
    final CriteriaQuery<table1> criteriaQuery = builder.createQuery(table1.class);
    final Root<table1> from = criteriaQuery.from(table1.class);
    final Predicate p1 = builder.equal(from.get(table1_.table2ID).get(table2_.table2ID), table2ID);
    final Predicate p2 = builder.equal(from.get(table1_.e), e);
    final Predicate p3 = builder.equal(from.get(table1_.isEnd), false);

    final Subquery<Long> sq1 = criteriaQuery.subquery(Long.class);
    final Root<table1> maxColumn1 = sq1.from(table1.class);
    sq1.select(builder.max(maxColumn1 .get(table1_.Column1)));

    final Predicate p4 = builder.in(from.get(table1_.Column1)).value(sq1);

    final Subquery<Long> sq2 = criteriaQuery.subquery(Long.class);
    final Root<table1> minColumn2 = criteriaQuery.from(table1.class);
    sq2.select(builder.min(minColumn2 .get(table1_.Column2)));

    final Predicate p5 = builder.in(from.get(table1_.Column2) ).value(sq2);

    criteriaQuery.select(from).where(builder.and(p1, p2, p3,p4,p5));

    final List<table1> liste= listByCriteriaQuery(criteriaQuery);
    if (!liste.isEmpty()) {
        return liste.get(0);
    }

    return null;
}
```

please tell me what's wrong with the form of the subqueries 
PS:I am a beginner

Comment: And what is the problem? What output do you expect, what output do you get? What id your debugging find so far?

Comment: i have edited the post  thank you

Comment: This last select has nothing after the from `(select min(generatedAlias1.Column2) from )`

Comment: yea thank you ,the probleme was in this line :final Root<table1> minColumn2 = criteriaQuery.from(table1.class);    instead of " criteriaQuery.from" i have to put "sq2 .from"